# python calling different class methods by user input with terminating existing one

Tags: python, python-3.x

i'm trying to build personal assistant which is running by voice command.it is working perfectly with if: elif: blocks. but i want to create more elegance way and shorten code a bit.i try to create modular structure but i cant manage to terminate running function by calling middleman function with command=false parameter

i need some guiding please

[image: the picture above you can see what am i try to build.]

main.py

```
from handler import middleman

while True:
    message = input("> ")
    if message != "":
        middleman(message) #lets say command is "play1" than next command "play2"
```

Handler.py

```
from music import Class1                                                             
from music import Class2

def func1(context, command):
    if command == True:
        x = Class1(context)
        x.run()  
    else:
        x.stop()  --> x not exist here gives error 

 def func2(context, command):
        if command == True:
            x = Class2(context)
            x.run()  
        else:
            x.stop()


def middleman(text):
    command = True
    if text == "stop":
        command = False
    function_name = globals()[text]
    function_name(command)
```

music.py

```
import logging
import threading
import time

import pygame


class Player(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, file_path, volume=1.0, start_time=0.0, master=None):
        print("player started")
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        # 传入主窗口的指针，用于触发主窗口事件(若有)
        self.master = master
        self.file_path = file_path
        # 音乐播放起点
        self.start_time = start_time
        # 用于控制音乐播放与停止
        self.stop_state = False
        # 用于控制音乐的暂停和恢复
        self.pause_state = False
        # 控制默认音量
        self.volume = volume
        # 初始化mixer
        pygame.mixer.init()  # 初始化音频
        self.track = pygame.mixer.music

    def set_volume(self, volume):
        self.volume = volume
        self.track.set_volume(self.volume)

    def get_volume(self):
        return self.volume

    def run(self,stop):
        print("stop word,stop")
        try:
            file = self.file_path
            self.track.load(file)  # 载入音乐文件
            self.track.set_volume(self.volume)  # 设置音量
            self.track.play(start=self.start_time)  # 开始播放
        except Exception as e:
            logging.warning(e)
            if self.master:
                self.master.event_generate("<<MusicError>>", when="tail")

        while self.stop_state:
            time.sleep(1)
            # 若停止播放或播放结束，则结束这个线程
            if self.stop_state:
                self.track.stop()  # 停止播放
                return
            elif not self.track.get_busy():
                if self.master:
                    self.master.event_generate("<<CouldMusicStop>>", when="tail")
                return
            elif not self.stop_state and self.pause_state:
                self.track.pause()  # 暂停播放
            elif not self.stop_state and not self.pause_state:
                self.track.unpause()  # 恢复播放
    def stop(self):
        self.stop_state=True
        self.player = None
```

Comment: Why does `Handler.play` do two completely different things, rather than having separate functions?

Comment: What means "can't manage"? Show what you try. What happens, what should happen?

Comment: i am calling middleman function over and over again each time i need to terminate running function (if it is not terminated already) if i call child function in middleman it will create new instance but i need to terminate existing instance. I edited question to to explain myself.sorry for my bad english.

Comment: @chepner: how can i call x.stop functioninside the middleman function  when i run midlleman again with command = False ?.  func1 instance will not be  exist inside middleman function isnt it ?

Comment: That's kind of my point. You need `x` to persist beyond a single call of `func1`, and neither `func1` nor `func2` should *be* a single function that behaves completely different depending on the value of a boolean argument.

Comment: is there any sample code which you can point.i can follow the rest